# How to verify an image exists within a specific element using Robot Framework

Tags: automation, robotframework

I am trying to verify that a specific image exists on a webpage in a specific element.  The image:

- Has no unique id
- Has no unique alt
- The src attribute contains a query string I am trying to ignore
- Appears multiple times on the page

I can't use Page Should Contain Image because it appears multiple times but I need to verify it appears in a specific table cell.  The image src looks like this:

```
${BaseUrl}/status_submitted.png?master_2017217_17-29
```

Here's the HTML surrounding the image:

```
<table id="mass_list" class="grid">
  <tr>
     <th class="shrink align_center">Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th class="shrink align_right">Submitted</th>
        <th class="shrink">Submitted By</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
           <td>
               <img src="https://{baseurl}/images/status_submitted.png?master_2017217_17-29" alt="Submitted" width="70" height="20" />
           </td>
           <td class="nowrap">
              Automation Test 1488321180.7

                <br />
                <small class="mute">
                    <strong>0</strong> of <strong>2</strong> records processed
                </small>

            </td>
           <td class="nowrap align_right">Yesterday at 4:33 PM</td>
           <td class="nowrap">Tina Tester</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
               <img src="https://{baseurl}/images/status_submitted.png?master_2017217_17-29" alt="Submitted" width="70" height="20" />
           </td>
           <td class="nowrap">
              Add an attribute

                <br />
                <small class="mute">
                    <strong>0</strong> of <strong>16</strong> records processed
                </small>                  
            </td>
           <td class="nowrap align_right">Yesterday at 8:06 AM</td>
           <td class="nowrap">Tina Tester</td>
        </tr>
```

I need to verify that just ${BaseUrl}/status_submitted.png exists on the page within a specific table cell or xpath location.  How do I do this?

Comment: Could we see the HTML for the image ?

Comment: Yes, added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example document this was a rather straight forward excersise for me using nothing more than Google Chrome itself. Put the contents of the example in a file with HTML/Body tags around it and then use the right-click inspect to inspect the element in the console. Right click again on the source tag and choose Copy>Xpath.

This will result in the following xPath: `//*[@id="mass_list"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/img` where the first number `tr[2]`is the row, and the second number `td[1]` is the column.

A second approach is to look at the image tag itself and filter based on the file path location of the images with that src attribute: `//img[contains(@src, "status_submitted.png")]`

Comment: Can you be more specific?  If I try Page should contain  xpath=.., this does not verify the image is located at the xpath.  If I try Element Should Contain, providing the xpath as the locator, and the src attribute as the expected value, I get an error since it's looking for text.  What keywords are you meaning?

Comment: @quietgrit Element Should Be Visible

Comment: @Todor, doesn't work because there is always an image at that xpath but it needs to be a specific image for the test to pass.

Comment: @Todor is correct.`Element Should Be Visible` will do the trick in combination with `xpath=//*[@id="mass_list"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/img` as this will only return 1 image. This is guaranteed by the `tr[2]/td[1]/` as it points to a specific cell in the table and the image it contains. If you also want to perform a check on the image file name itself, then use the following: `xpath=//*[@id="mass_list"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/img[contains(@src, "status_submitted.png")]`. If this doesn't work for you, please provide more information on what it is that you want to test.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, checking that the image src name exists in the specific table cell is what I was after and the combo .. Element Should Be Visible | xpath=//*[@id="mass_list"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/img[contains(@s‌​rc, "status_submitted.png")] does the trick, thank you!